# How to hide content on mobile in the functions.php file - woocommerce

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I have inserted an image onto my woo-commerce single product page using the below hook and code written into my functions.php file:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', add_content_on_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary',1);

function add_content_on_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary() {
    
      echo "<img src='https://mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/blocks.png' >" ;
}
```

I only want this image to display on mobile and not desktop. Is there any code I can add to this in my functions.php file to achieve this?

Comment: You could use [`wp_is_mobile()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/) to sniff for a mobile device.

Comment: I'd be careful with this `wp_is_mobile()`. It does not JUST detect small screens.  Check the link Pat sent.  You should just use css and media queries.  Add a class to your image in your code and make it only show on small screens.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest method would be assign the image a class and display:none it based on media query.